# When is the derivative of an invertible transformation equal to the invertible transformation of the derivative

Tags: transformation, euler-lagrange-equation

Suppose I have some coordinates $q_i$ ($i=1,2,...,n$) and consider an invertible transformation thereof to some other set of coordinates, $x_j = x_j(q_1,...,q_n)$ ($j=1,2,...n$).

My textbook (Shankar's quantum mechanics textbook, in Chapter 2 when discussing changes of coordinates in configuration space in the classical Lagrangian picture -- this is equation 2.7.7, the first equality, for those who have the book) states that
$$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=\frac{dq_i}{dt}$$
if we write the right-hand side in terms of the $x_i$. This seems to me to be to be incorrect in general, and I'm hoping someone can confirm.

Comment: Makes no sense to me - actually I don't know what it would even mean to "write the right-hand side in terms of the $x_j$"...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Since $q_i = q_i(x_1,...x_n)$ we can write the RHS in terms of the $x_i$. I think that makes sense, at least in my head?

Comment: No that's not right. It should be $\frac{dx_i}{dt}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}\frac{dq_j}{dt}$ (with the usual caveats regarding sloppiness of notation). And regarding the first equal sign, I suggest you ignore it :)

Comment: @EE18 Thanks. But curiously, saying we can write the RHS in terms of the $x_j$ does not really help me understand how we'd do that

Comment: @peek-a-boo Do you have Shankar? I agree that the first equals sign is dubious (wrong indeed, as you point out), the last few are fine.

Comment: yes I do, and I'm not sure what he intended with that equal sign

Comment: @peek-a-boo Super, thank you for checking for me. Seems to me like a typo or something.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I know this is highly irregular, but can I ask you to take a peek at the one other related question I posted?